# AzureContainerApps@1 task fails with Unable to authenticate against ACR instance

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-registry, azure-container-apps

I am trying to update a containerApp from a dockerimage in ACR built in previous step through Azure DevOps pipeline running with VMSS agent. The variable
**acrContainerRegistry** contains value **myregistry.azurecr.io**

```
    - stage: Build
// defined jobs 
    - task: Docker@2
          displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
          inputs:
            command: buildAndPush
            repository: $(acrImageRepository)
            dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
            containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryConn)
            tags: |
              $(tag)
- stage: DeployContainerApp
//defined jobs
       - task: AzureContainerApps@1
         inputs:
           azureSubscription: $(armConn)
           acrName: $(acrContainerRegistry)
           containerAppName: $(CONTAINER_APP_NAME)
           resourceGroup: $(RG_NAME)
           imageToDeploy: $(acrContainerRegistry)/$(acrImageRepository)-$(Build.SourceBranchName):latest
        containerAppEnvironment: $(CONTAINER_APP_ENV_NAME)
        location: $(CONTAINER_APP_ENV_LOCATION_NAME)
        ingress: "external"
        targetPort: 80
```

The docker task is successful and image is pushed to acr, The **AzureContainerApps@1** task fails with this error

```
    /usr/bin/bash -c CA_ADO_TASK_ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az acr login --name myregistry.azurecr.io --output json --expose-token --only-show-errors | jq -r '.accessToken'); 
docker login myregistry.azurecr.io.azurecr.io -u 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 -p $CA_ADO_TASK_ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN > /dev/null 2>&1
    ##[error]Unable to run provided bash command 'CA_ADO_TASK_ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az acr login --name myregistry.azurecr.io --output json --expose-token --only-show-errors | jq -r '.accessToken'); docker login myregistry.azurecr.io.azurecr.io -u 000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 -p $CA_ADO_TASK_ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN > /dev/null 2>&1'.
    ##[error]Unable to authenticate against ACR instance 'myregistry.azurecr.io.azurecr.io' with access token.
    ##[error]The process '/usr/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
```

Here i notice that docker is trying to login with a extra **azurecr.io**

**myregistry.azurecr.io.azurecr.io**. is this the reason for failure? I am not sure how this gets appended?

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 0):

> **myregistry.azurecr.io.azurecr.io**. is this the reason for failure?

yes @coder. adding extra .azurecr.io to container registry URL causing the issue.

I tried executing your code in my environment to identify the issue, I encountered the same [error](https://i.imgur.com/E70Plwy.png) as you did.

To resolve the issue, I modified the Azure Container Apps task by providing a different name for the `acrName` argument, as shown in the screenshot you provided.

[image]

Here is the updated code that I executed, and I received the expected results:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: '$(dockerRegistryConn)'
    repository: '$(acrImageRepository)'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
    tags: |
      $(Build.BuildId)
      latest

- task: AzureContainerApps@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(armConn)
    acrName: $(acrContainerName)        # provide conatiner registry name here. In my case it is 'acrvjy'
    containerAppName: $(CONTAINER_APP_NAME)
    resourceGroup: $(RG_NAME)
    imageToDeploy: $(acrContainerRegistry)/$(acrImageRepository):latest #provide the full name of the repository. In my case it is  acrvjy.azurecr.io/pyimg:latests
    containerAppEnvironment: $(CONTAINER_APP_ENV_NAME)
    location: $(CONTAINER_APP_ENV_LOCATION_NAME)
    ingress: "external"
    targetPort: 80
```

Output: https://i.imgur.com/V2LcTX3.png